# Display my custom vscode language extension suggestions on top

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have built a vscode language extension for python that suggests words based on a certain AI model trained on my dataset. While i use this extension i have also installed the Microsoft python extension. The suggestions from both extensions show up alright, but i would like those from my extension to show up right at the top. I believe VSCODE assigns a certain score to these CompletionItems but i do not know how to bump up these scores. Is there a way of getting it done ? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use [suggest explain mode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75500) to investigate why your completion items are not ranked as high

Comment: Thank you Matt, this helps. I am taking a look at this.